# Reading <media:thumbnail /> tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, rss, tags

I'm using jquery to read rss tags and their contents. Accessing simple tags like `<title>` is pretty simple:

```
$(this).find('title').text();
```

But the thing is rss feeds have funny tags like:

```
<media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/52693000/jpg/_52693997_011963628-1.jpg" />
```

And of course, `$(this).find('media:thumbnail');` is not working... Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

```
$('media\\:thumbnail');
```

it is called name space the colon thingy and you would need to escape the colon because the colon is also used for things like `:empty`, `:checked` etc...

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. Just tried it, but still looks like it doesn't work... $(this).find('media\\:thumbnail'); is returning [object Object] but looks like an empty object though...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DJ3NB/ here is a working demo also check that your <media:thumbnail /> tag has a space after the openning tag `<` just incase you have not noticed